# what is default memory policy flag for malloc?

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

In a numa system when malloc is called without using set_mempolicy, what is the default mempolicy flag being used in kernel for this allocation? Is it MPOL_DEFAULT or MPOL_INTERLEAVED ?

Comment: So did you check it with `get_mempolicy`? `when malloc is called` - you mean `numa_alloc` or `malloc`? Wouldn't the name suggest the default mempolicy is `MPOL_DEFAULT`?...

Comment: i meant malloc alone on numa machine, Added required answer below.

Answer (score 1):

In mm/mempolicy.c

/*
 * run-time system-wide default policy => local allocation
 */

```
static struct mempolicy default_policy = {
    .refcnt = ATOMIC_INIT(1), /* never free it */
    .mode = MPOL_PREFERRED,
    .flags = MPOL_F_LOCAL,
};
```

So default mempolicy is MPOL_PREFERRED.